# Use armature from newer project in older project

Tags: modeling, objects, armature

I have a project with a 3D model which has armature with pose attached to it. I progressively did changes to the model and i made a couple of project backups of it at each "step" i made, but now i need to go back to a previous version of the project to modify some irreversible changes.

But i don't want to lose the pose i made to the model since i spent a lot of time doing it.

Is there any way to export the armature/pose of the latest project backup to use it in the old project backup?